# Oracle Real cluster application?

Tags: oracle, rac

My application is working in Real cluster application(RAC)in production. I am new to RAC and  gone through this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiPNDQQtgOo&t=) .

My understanding after reading this

1. RAC uses more than one node only for data processing the data in memory but still uses one node to store data
2. processing can be like applying index, order by clause, any function etc
3. So its the load distribution at processing level not at data storage level

Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Data is stored on shared storage. Nodes do not store any data, they just process it.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.